# LINQ Query from string

Tags: string, linq, build, field

Ok, I have found a lot of sites that mention this problem, but none quite match what I need to do. I have a program that generates a ton of datatables based on data I am collecting from Amazon web services.  I am trying to write a single function that will allow me to search for a particular string in ANY column of a supplied datatable.

In version 1 of my program, I manually built me query based on a predefined table structure:

```
 newbie = RawEC2Results.AsEnumerable().Where(p => p.Field<string>("AccountID").Contains(FilterTagText.Text) || 
p.Field<string>("Profile").Contains(FilterTagText.Text) ||
p.Field<string>("Region").Contains(FilterTagText.Text) ||
p.Field<string>("Name").Contains(FilterTagText.Text) ||
p.Field<string>("InstanceID").Contains(FilterTagText.Text) ||
p.Field<string>("AvailabilityZone").Contains(FilterTagText.Text) ||
p.Field<string>("Platform").Contains(FilterTagText.Text) ||
p.Field<string>("Status").Contains(FilterTagText.Text) ||
p.Field<string>("Events").Contains(FilterTagText.Text) ||
p.Field<string>("EventList").Contains(FilterTagText.Text) ||
p.Field<string>("Tags").Contains(FilterTagText.Text) ||
p.Field<string>("Priv_IP").Contains(FilterTagText.Text) ||
p.Field<string>("Pub_IP").Contains(FilterTagText.Text) ||
p.Field<string>("Pub_DNS").Contains(FilterTagText.Text) ||
p.Field<string>("State").Contains(FilterTagText.Text) ||
p.Field<string>("vType").Contains(FilterTagText.Text) ||
p.Field<string>("iType").Contains(FilterTagText.Text) ||
p.Field<string>("SecurityGroups").Contains(FilterTagText.Text));
```

This is tedious to maintain, as I must update every time I change the columns to add new data.  I can generate a string to generate a query based on a any given table, but can't figure out how to process it.

```
            string nocasequery = "p=> ";
        int colno = Table2Filter.Columns.Count;

        for (int i =0; i < Table2Filter.Columns.Count  ;i++)
        {
            if (i == colno)
            {
                CASEquery +=   @"p.Field<string>(""+Table2Filter.Columns[i]+  "").Contains(FilterTagText.Text) ; ";
                nocasequery += @"p.Field<string>(""+Table2Filter.Columns[i]+  "").ToLower().Contains(FilterTagText.Text) ; ";
            }
```

So,  any ideas?  This is not a database,  and the examples I did find didn't work on datatables.If I could just pass this string to a Where clause my job would be done. I cant figure out how to build this query any other way than by hand, and that blows chunkskis. Or if there is a way to tell Linq to search every column without my explicitly calling them out?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the only way to accomplish this is to use the `Microsoft.CSharp and System.CodeDom.Compiler namespaces` as this will allow you to compile your string into an assembly to be run.

'http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime'

That link should provide you with some guidance on how to accomplish this!

Edit: By this, I mean processing the string that you created.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create such a query dynamicaly yourself. Just use the `DataTable.Select` method for this that has a sql-like syntax:

```
void Main()
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("foo", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("bar", typeof(string));

    dt.Rows.Add("baz", "baaz");
    dt.Rows.Add("qux", "quux");

    var results = dt.Select("foo like '%a%'"); // finds baz
}
```

You can list all the columns and build the query string from them that for this example would be:

> ```
> foo like '%{0}%' OR bar like '%{0}%'
> ```

```
var columnNames =
    dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Select(c => c.ColumnName);

var query = string.Join(" OR ", columnNames.Select(x => x + " like '%{0}%'"));

query = string.Format(query, "a");
var results = dt.Select(query);
```

See

[DataTable.Select Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx)

[DataView RowFilter Syntax [C#]](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/)

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to check if *any* field value of a data row contains the filter text, you can loop through the rows, and per row through its values and check if any value in a row `Contains()` the filter text:

```
var text = FilterTagText.Text;
var matches = dt.AsEnumerable() // dt is a DataTable
                .Where(r => dt.Columns.OfType<DataColumn>()
                              .Select(dc => (r[dc.Caption] ?? string.Empty).ToString())
                              .Any(s => s.Contains(text)))
```